# ios: UITableVIewCell expand not working as expected

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

My TableView cell has a button. On click, I want to expand the cell. For expanding I'm changing the height of the cell on button click and reload the row. But when one row is expanded and then I try to expand another row, the behaviour is not as expected. The previously expanded row closes instead of clicked row.

Also, sometimes I've to click the button twice to expand.

```
public class ProgramMeasurementDetailsTableViewSource : UITableViewSource
{

    List<ProgramMeasurementDetail> mList;

    string HeaderIdentfier = "programMeasurementDetailsHeader";
    string CellIdentifier = "programMeasurementDetailsCell";
    int TAG_CHECKBOX = 61;
    int TAG_LABEL_VITAL_NAME = 62;
    int TAG_LABEL_GOAL = 63;
    int TAG_BUTTON_EDIT = 64;
    int TAG_VIEW_HEADER_COLUMN_SEPARATOR = 66;
    int TAG_VIEW_ROW_COLUMN_SEPARATOR = 65;
    List<bool> expandStatusList = new List<bool>();
    UITableView tableView;

    public ProgramMeasurementDetailsTableViewSource(List<ProgramMeasurementDetail> mList, UITableView tableView)
    {
        this.tableView = tableView;
        this.mList = mList;
        for (int i = 0; i < mList.Count; i++)
            expandStatusList.Add(false);
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return mList.Count;
    }

    public override nfloat GetHeightForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        return 32;
    }

    public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (expandStatusList[indexPath.Row])
            return 70;
        else
            return 32;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier);
        }
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)cell.ViewWithTag(TAG_CHECKBOX);
        UILabel vitalNameLabel = (UILabel)cell.ViewWithTag(TAG_LABEL_VITAL_NAME);
        UILabel goalLabel = (UILabel)cell.ViewWithTag(TAG_LABEL_GOAL);
        UIButton editGoalButton = (UIButton)cell.ViewWithTag(TAG_BUTTON_EDIT);
        editGoalButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
         {
             expandStatusList[indexPath.Row] = !expandStatusList[indexPath.Row];
             tableView.ReloadRows(new Foundation.NSIndexPath[] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);

         };

        .....
        return cell;
    }
}
```

I tried moving the button click event handling inside the if (cell == null), then but button click/expand is not working at all. I put breakpoint and it seems that part never gets executed.

I've the cell layout designed in storyboard.

I've struggling with this problem for quite sometime now. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Does the bug you see happen when you scroll the list up and down? This is happening because you are wiring up the `TouchUpInside` event handler in the `GetCell` method and then it never get unhooked when the cell is reused, so you end up with multiple cells wired to the same handler or even multiple handlers!

In general, you don't want to do these types on things in the `GetCell` method, it should only be used to `DequeueReusableCell` or create a new one. Everything else should be done within a custom cell.

Looking at your code example, it doesn't look like you are using a custom cell, so what you could do is this:

1.) In `GetCell` set the tag of the button as the row of the IndexPath

```
editGoalButton.Tag = indexPath.Row;
```

2.) In `ProgramMeasurementDetailsTableViewSource` Create a separate method for your event handler:

```
private void ToggleRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as UIButton;
    expandStatusList[btn.Tag] = !expandStatusList[btn.Tag];
    tableView.ReloadRows(new Foundation.NSIndexPath[] { NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(btn.Tag, 0) }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);
}
```

3.) In `GetCell` Unhook before you rehook the `TouchUpInside` handler:

```
editGoalButton.TouchUpInside -= ToggleRow;
editGoalButton.TouchUpInside += ToggleRow;
```

While this will make sure that the button is only hooked up once, it really isn't the right way to handle a situation like this. You should be using a custom cell and doing all the wiring in the cell and then the unhook and clean up in the `PrepareForReuse` override in `UITableViewCell`. I would highly recommend going though this [Xamarin tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_3_-_customizing_a_table's_appearance/)

If you do go through it...notice how consolidated the `GetCell` method is.

**--UPDATE--**
In your `CustomCell` class:

```
private EventHandler _tapAction;
public void Setup(EventHandler tapAction, int row, ....)
{
     //keep a reference to the action, so we can unhook it later
     _tapAction = tapAction;
     editGoalButton.Tag = row;
     ....
     editGoalButton.TouchUpInside += _tapAction;
}

public override void PrepareForReuse()
{
     ....
     editGoalButton.TouchUpInside -= _tapAction;
     _tapAction = null;
}
```

And you would just pass through the `ToggleRow` method as the Action parameter when you call `Setup` in `GetCell`.

Comment: So I should not use storyboard for designing cells? Now I've the cell designed in storyboard. Is it possible to use it as the cell's design in the CustomCell class?

Comment: You can use a cell from Storyboard as well. Just make sure the `TableView Cell Style` is set to `Custom` and give it a class name. Xamarin will generate `.cs` files for the custom class. The beginning portion of this tutorial will show you how to generate the code behind file: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/autosizing-row-height/

Comment: where do I define the button TouchUpinside when using custom cell class? Do I put in the Custom cell class. If yes, How do I reload the tableview row from there?

Comment: I passed a reference of the TableView and TableViewSource to the UpdateCell method and everything seems to be working as expected. But is it the proper way to do it?

Comment: You should be able to get away with passing an Action for the TouchUpInside event and the row of the cell. See updated answer.